# Duplicate (synonym) tag shown in tag list

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

If I search "revi" in https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags , I get [reviewing] listed although clicking it brings to [peer-review].

[image: Tag list]

Comment: This is the expected behavior. What's your question?

Comment: An answer could link a MSE answer which explains why that's the expected behaviour, for instance.

Comment: If you want to know *why*, ask on MSE. Questions about system-wide features are best asked there.

Comment: [Relevant comment](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2109/two-textbooks-tags/2110?noredirect=1#comment8295_2110)